# Does SFTP put operation have size limit?

Tags: linux, sftp

I use SFTP to transfer file from local to remote Linux machine. However it fails. I tested it and come to a conclusion that, when transfer file is bigger than `testScp.txt1`, it fails and the machine will also be down; when transfer file is less than `testScp.txt3` it is ok!  Why ?

```
testScp.txt1  fileSize: 18944 
testScp.txt3  fileSize: 18228 

sftp> put testScp.txt3 /home/yqiu
Uploading testScp.txt3 to /home/yqiu/testScp.txt3
testScp.txt3                100%   18KB  17.8KB/s   00:00

sftp> put testScp.txt1 /home/yqiu
Uploading testScp.txt1 to /home/yqiu/testScp.txt1
testScp.txt1                0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
```

Comment: There's definitely no limit. Does it fail with some error message or does it stall?

Comment: no message but install and network is down, must reboot machine

Answer (score 1):

Most Linux systems use [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/), which doesn't even have a way to configure size limits for file transfers. The intermittent failures which you're experiencing  may be triggered by something else or completely random.